# c# - Custom Notepad loading in text

Tags: c#

So I have made my own custom Notepad program everything works just like a normal notepad but now I want to launch it from .txt files. I change my default launch program for .txt files to my NotePad2.0. The problem is when I i launch the from a .txt file it doesn't load in the text. Anyone got any ideas? I'm looking for a possible file path to the .txt file or some other way that I can pull the text out of the .txt file on open.
(other details: I am talking about when I am in a File Explorer or on the Desktop and I open a .txt file. I want the text that is in that .txt file to load into my program.)
Thank you to anyone who helps/looks over my problem!

Comment: Are you looking at the `args` parameter in the Main method?

Comment: Most likely you're missing, or mis-using, the `object[] args` of your application's `Main()`

Comment: looking into it ill let you know in a few minutes

Comment: Nope args is not what im looking for. so say im in C:\Users\Stststudar\Desktop\Notes and i click on a .txt file inside this location(the NotePad2.0 program is not running yet) I want to be able to find a location like C:\Users\Stststudar\Desktop\Notes\testNotes.txt (when i click the .txt file and it launches my NotePad2.0 program). The location where the app was launched from so i can then load in the text from this location.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. So what does `args` contain when you double-click a txt file if not the path to that file?

Comment: Spend a minute searching the framework before asking a question https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You definitely want to use the `args` parameter to the `Main` method. There could be something missing in your association though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx) method to retrieve the filename which is opened and then read all the text inside your file using the [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) method and load the resultant string into your app (maybe in a textbox):

```
textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetCommanLineArgs()[1]);
```

Where textBox1 is the text container in your app.

After that, if you open a text file with your app, you will see that all its text is properly loaded into your TextBox.

Note that the first argument is the name of the executable itself. Thus you need the second argument. Also, you might want to check if there is a second argument because otherwise it will crash if you directly open the executable. You might also want additional checks like if the file is a text (.txt) file or not and so on.

For that, you can do something like this:

```
var args = Environment.GetCommanLineArgs();
if (args.Length > 1)
{
     textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[1]);
}
```

Comment: AWESOME!! Thank you so much this worked perfectly!! I have been stuck on this problem for a while now i appreciate the help it works exactly how i wanted it!

Comment: @Stststudar Consider upvoting and accepting this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I totally would and have tried but i need 15 reputation to do so :( so for now all i can do is say my thanks in text.

Comment: @Stststudar 15 reputation?!?. As far as I know, its fifteen minutes. you can accept an answer at any rep level. try clicking the check mark next to this answer. if it turns to green, you will know that you have successfully accepted it.